# Flip order of each first pair of arrays within an array

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array like below, where under the array key "period" you have an array which contains four arrays where you can see that it goes open close, open close, i want it to be close open, close open, but each pair of arrays (open & close) still need to retain their order in the parent array format. I really hope that makes sense! I've been plugging away at this for ages but i just cannot seem to get it to iterate correctly and maintain that order.

Any help would be really gratefully received. Thank you.

```
array(1) {
  ["opening_hours"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["periods"]=>
    array(12) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["open"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["day"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["time"]=>
          string(4) "0730"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["close"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["day"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["time"]=>
          string(4) "1200"
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["open"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["day"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["time"]=>
          string(4) "1600"
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      array(1) {
        ["close"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["day"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["time"]=>
          string(4) "2345"
        }
      }
      [4]=>
      array(1) {
        ["open"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["day"]=>
          string(1) "2"
          ["time"]=>
          string(4) "0745"
        }
      }
      [5]=>
      array(1) {
        ["close"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["day"]=>
          string(1) "2"
          ["time"]=>
          string(4) "1200"
        }
      }
      [6]=>
      array(1) {
        ["open"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["day"]=>
          string(1) "2"
          ["time"]=>
          string(4) "1600"
        }
      }
      [7]=>
      array(1) {
        ["close"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["day"]=>
          string(1) "2"
          ["time"]=>
          string(4) "2345"
        }
      }
      [8]=>
      array(1) {
        ["open"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["day"]=>
          string(1) "3"
          ["time"]=>
          string(4) "0800"
        }
      }
      [9]=>
      array(1) {
        ["close"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["day"]=>
          string(1) "3"
          ["time"]=>
          string(4) "1200"
        }
      }
      [10]=>
      array(1) {
        ["open"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["day"]=>
          string(1) "3"
          ["time"]=>
          string(4) "1600"
        }
      }
      [11]=>
      array(1) {
        ["close"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["day"]=>
          string(1) "3"
          ["time"]=>
          string(4) "2345"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem in having them this way? Anyways, they are not ordered.

Comment: Are you serious? If something comes one after another, they are in some form of order aren't they? As for what is the problem having them ordered this way, well, it just needs to be for my purposes! Thanks for the input though....

Comment: Still am not clear. Anyways. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to believe your array is like this

```
$array = array(
        "opening_hours" => array(
                "periods" => array(
                        0 => array("open" => array("day" => "1","time" => "0730")),
                        1 => array("close" => array("day" => "1","time" => "1200")),
                        2 => array("open" => array("day" => "1","time" => "1600")),
                        3 => array("close" => array("day" => "1","time" => "2345")),
                        4 => array("open" => array("day" => "2","time" => "0745")),
                        5 => array("close" => array("day" => "2","time" => "1200")),
                        6 => array("open" => array("day" => "2","time" => "1600")),
                        7 => array("close" => array("day" => "2","time" => "2345")),
                        8 => array("open" => array("day" => "3","time" => "0800")),
                        9 => array("close" => array("day" => "3","time" => "1200")),
                        10 => array("open" => array("day" => "3","time" => "1600")),
                        11 => array("close" => array("day" => "3","time" => "2345")))));
```

Swapping Position

```
$final = array();
$total = count($array['opening_hours']['periods']);

for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i += 2) {

    if (isset($array['opening_hours']['periods'][$i + 1])) {
        $final[] = $array['opening_hours']['periods'][$i + 1];
    }

    $final[] = $array['opening_hours']['periods'][$i];
}

var_dump($final);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'close' => 
        array
          'day' => string '1' (length=1)
          'time' => string '1200' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array
      'open' => 
        array
          'day' => string '1' (length=1)
          'time' => string '0730' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array
      'close' => 
        array
          'day' => string '1' (length=1)
          'time' => string '2345' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array
      'open' => 
        array
          'day' => string '1' (length=1)
          'time' => string '1600' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array
      'close' => 
        array
          'day' => string '2' (length=1)
          'time' => string '1200' (length=4)
  5 => 
    array
      'open' => 
        array
          'day' => string '2' (length=1)
          'time' => string '0745' (length=4)
  6 => 
    array
      'close' => 
        array
          'day' => string '2' (length=1)
          'time' => string '2345' (length=4)
  7 => 
    array
      'open' => 
        array
          'day' => string '2' (length=1)
          'time' => string '1600' (length=4)
  8 => 
    array
      'close' => 
        array
          'day' => string '3' (length=1)
          'time' => string '1200' (length=4)
  9 => 
    array
      'open' => 
        array
          'day' => string '3' (length=1)
          'time' => string '0800' (length=4)
  10 => 
    array
      'close' => 
        array
          'day' => string '3' (length=1)
          'time' => string '2345' (length=4)
  11 => 
    array
      'open' => 
        array
          'day' => string '3' (length=1)
          'time' => string '1600' (length=4)
```

Comment: Thanks Baba, that looks great to me, i'll give it a try! Cheers!!

Comment: Hey Baba, just one thing, your code takes away my parent arrays of [opening_hours] & [periods]. How can i have it so that it still has the same data structure as when it started out?

Comment: Oh sorry, ignore that, i was being dense!

Comment: @bjohnb its ok we all have our moments :)